# Updating a JSON array object with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5.3

How can i update the following JSON object dynamically using php?

this my json.

```
 {
    "1":
        {
            "value0":
                    {
                        "id":0,
                        "status":0,
                        "quantity":"110"
                    },
            "value1":
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "status":1,
                        "quantity":"120"
                    }
        }
    "2":
        {
            value0":
                    {
                        "id":0,
                        "status":0,
                        "quantity":"132"
                    },
            "value1":
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "status":1,
                        "quantity":"123"
                    },
        }
}
```

I want to change the status of value0 from key 1, to 1.
How can I acheive this?

Comment: Convert JSON to array by using json_decode. Make the update in the array. Then convert the array into JSON by using json_encode.

Comment: $new_data = json_decode($data,true);  $new_data[1]["value0"]["status"]=1;   $data = json_encode($new_data); echo $data;

Comment: Oh thank you @manian, but when I tried json_endcode, my json changed to `{"1":{"value0":{"status":1}}}`.

Comment: sorry check my below answer .it will work as you expected

Comment: @JYoThI oh thanks, i really it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use **json_decode()** and **json_enocde()**

```
$data = json_decode($data,true);  
$data["1"]["value0"]["status"]=1;   
$data = json_encode($data);
echo $data;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be ``["1"]`` instead of ``[1]`` since its an assoc array and [1] would trigger second array element, which is key "2"?