# Update JSON Object PHP

Tags: php

I want to update my JSON object according to user input using PHP ,
my JSON file looks like this :

```
[
  {
    id=1,
    text= "Sam",
  },
  {
   id=2,
    text= "Jack",
  }
]
```

I want to update the text with what the user will input

Comment: use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn your json string to a PHP array, then update it.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106626/updating-a-json-array-object-with-php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a JSON array object with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106626/updating-a-json-array-object-with-php)

Comment: Which text will you update, id=1 or 2 and how will you know which one?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check your json format because it is not valid. This is my code, hope this will help you.

```
//your input
$id = 1;
$input = "john";

//decode your json
$info = json_decode($json);
foreach ($info as $data) {
    if ($data->id == $id) {   //find the id
        $data->text = $input; //update json object text depends on the user input
    }
}
```

then you can return the info to display update

```
return $info;
```